# Docker Container not running simultaneously

Tags: windows, docker, server, docker-container

I am trying to run multiple docker Container in a single network but as soon as I reached to 7 container this problem started. If I start one container other will exit automatically. I have increased memory to 3 GB and CPU to 100%. Now this looks like a resource problem but how do we solve it

Comment: In which environment are you running this? Linux/Windows and version.
Also, are you running all Docker Containers on same machine?

Comment: i am running it in windows and version is 17.12.0-ce. Yes all container are on same machine and network

Comment: Have you looked into the log file when 1st Docker Container exits?

Comment: Yes i have but it is not helping with this problem since  container is exited to it will all the error raised after getting exited like connection exceptions which have been thrown because container is exited. So question remains same why it was exited.